# complex exponential with cosine term

Tags: integration

First of all, thank you. 
I have found one integral, that I think that it should not be very difficult to resolve, but for Mathematica 9 is impossible, but I think that it should be analytical!

the Integral is
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}Cos[\theta] e^{(-I k   \rho s ( 
   Cos[\alpha] Cos[\theta] + Sin[\alpha] Sin[\theta])}\text{d}\theta)
$$

If I have no the cosine term I know that it is the zero-Bessel function, but whit it, I have no idea

Thanks

Comment: did you copy that directly from Mathematica??

Comment: I believe a $d\theta$ or $d\alpha $  is missing

Comment: Your $\theta$ in the exponential is different from the $\Theta$ outside.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have edited it and I have added $d\theta$, I copy directly from Mathematica,xd

Comment: Maybe the reason Mathematica did not give an answer is that it strangely thinks $\theta$ and $\Theta$ are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \cos{\theta} \; e^{-i x \cos{(\theta - \alpha)}}$$
Change variables to $\theta=\phi+\alpha$ and expand the integrand to get

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \cos{\theta} \; e^{-i x \cos{(\theta - \alpha)}} = \cos{\alpha} \int_{-\alpha}^{2 \pi-\alpha} d\phi\cos{\phi} \; e^{-i x \cos{\phi}} - \sin{\alpha} \int_{-\alpha}^{2 \pi-\alpha} d\phi\sin{\phi} \; e^{-i x \cos{\phi}}$$

The second integral on the RHS is zero.  The first integral, however, may be written in terms of a Bessel function:

$$\int_{-\alpha}^{2 \pi-\alpha} d\phi\cos{\phi} \; e^{-i x \cos{\phi}} = i \frac{d}{dx} J_0(x) = -i J_1(x)$$

The integral is then

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \cos{\theta} \; e^{-i x \cos{(\theta - \alpha)}} = -i \cos{\alpha} J_1(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer written by rlgordonma is perfect

I have found a bug in Mathematica 9.

The integral that I have posted ,i.e., $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}Cos(\theta)e^{ixCos(\theta-\alpha)}d\theta $$

cannot be done by mathematica 9, nevertheless, if I write

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}Cos(x)e^{iaCos(x-y)}dx
$$

it gives me the correct answer.

I adressed some links with the same issue

http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7844694

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/why-does-mathematica-give-the-wrong-answer-when-integrating/2743#2743

http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/tagged/Bessel%20functions.html

Thank you